# adding search capability to my map

Tags: search, dictionary

Can someone please explain to me how I can get the search functionality from this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

to work with your map when you have followed this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

I've basically done both tutorials, just learning and I can make them work flawlessly seperately, however i want to port across the searching options from the first tutorial when having a map created via the first one.

I have the following:
sql database with all my info
XML output working perfectly
all markers working nicely with custom icons from the sql xml output
searchbox + all textbox/buttons in place.

Now i just need to make it work lol, no code in place for it at the moment. I just want it to search and display certain locations within a certain radisu

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks alot :)